# two raspberry pi 4 communication via BLE

Tags: python, pi-4, bluetooth, bluez

I need to pass a stream of data from raspberry pi 4 to pi 4. and I downloaded /home/pi/Downloads/bluez-5.50/test/example-advertisement,and can successfully run it,two pi can connect,but I don't know how to use other examples,gatt-client and gatt server,hope you can tell me some information.

1. let pi be a BTLE peripherial,there are some errors when i use command:nmp install bleno
2. how to use /bluez-5.50/test/gatt-client and gatt server

Comment: Does it need to be BLE? It might be easier with Bluetooth Classic. There are libraries like [Bluedot Comm](https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btcommapi.html#bluetoothserver) that can help. Or you can do it directly with Python Sockets as this blog shows: https://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/

Comment: Thank you ,it needs to use BLE, my goal is to pass a stream of data between raspberry pi and BLE device,I can use Bluetooth Classic and Python Sockets to pass data,but I want to use BLE,thank you again!

Comment: Welcome -- but as originally written your question was too many questions rolled into one.  For that reason I removed the last one, which was also too vague (if you want to ask for code, you need to post code you have tried and explain what it was supposed to do and what actually happened).  Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.

Comment: Creating a GATT Server (peripheral) is a lot more work than creating  a GATT client (central). Developing both ends of the link at the same time is hard if this is your first time. Is it a BLE Peripheral you want to connect to? There is a useful study guide at: https://www.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-resources/bluetooth-for-linux/ . To test a BLE peripheral using a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) and it will help you discover the UUIDs etc of that device

Comment: Use ethernet or WiFi it's some orders of magnitude easier.